# How to get an Individual Taxpayer Identification Number as a non-US resident?

Tags: united-states, irs, non-resident

How to get an Individual Taxpayer Identification Number (ITIN) as a non-US resident?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayer-identification-numbers-tin), you need to file an [IRS Form W-7, IRS Application for Individual Taxpayer Identification Number](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7).

> To obtain an ITIN, you must complete [IRS Form W-7, IRS Application for Individual Taxpayer Identification Number](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7). The Form W-7 requires documentation substantiating foreign/alien status and true identity for each individual. You may either mail the documentation, along with the Form W-7, to the address shown in the Form W-7 Instructions, present it at IRS walk-in offices, or process your application through an [Acceptance Agent](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/acceptance-agent-program) authorized by the IRS. [Form W-7(SP), Solicitud de Número de Identificación Personal del Contribuyente del Servicio de Impuestos Internos](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7) is available for use by Spanish speakers.

If you already knew all that, please give us more information on the problem you are facing.